# Time-based Workflow Rules: based on field with workflow update TODAY()

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

Trying to create a sales SLA process declaratively. I have a date field (Status Change Date) which is updated with a workflow rule to TODAY() whenever the Status field is edited. I'm trying to create a task when the status hasn't changed for 21 days, so I was using a Time-based workflow rule... Trigger when status = working, time-based workflow is 21 days from status change date create a task.

I'm not sure that it's working. To test I set the time-based workflow down to 1 day, changed the status which triggered the Status Change Date to update. I checked back today, but I did not see the task.

I looked into some documentation and found [this](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US). The line that concerns me is the following:

```
Time triggers don't support minutes or seconds.
Time triggers can't reference the following:
    DATE or DATETIME fields containing automatically derived functions, such as TODAY or NOW.
    Formula fields that include related-object merge fields.
```

Does this mean that the time-based workflow won't use the Status Change Date because it was set by the workflow rule to TODAY()?

If that's true, is there any declaritive way to trigger a task when a record is sitting in a status after a period of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to do this.
It will use the status change date assuming you are not using a formula field. 
Assuming you have just set the field using TODAY it will be fine to use.

The trigger just cant reference a nondeterministic formula.
Try checking on the work flow to update field check reevaluate workflow criteria.

I created a workflow that updates a field to today based on status changed. The second workflow uses a formula that is set to true and will start a task (or in your case email) if the field value is not updated within the time period. - It creates the task every period unless the field is updated and stops it from sending.

You can use time-based workflow monitoring to help debug and check if its working. It should show up.
setup->monitoring->time based workflow

Comment: Thanks - That's what I thought. What keeps throwing me off is that I'm not seeing the workflow in queue under the time base workflow monitoring. I think I read somewhere that it takes up to an hour to be put into queue - does that sound right to you?

My trigger is on create/edited to meet criteria check for ISPICKVAL(Status,"Sold"). I have a record that I created and set in Sold status but I'm not seeing anything in the queue.

Comment: I think I just realized why it wasn't going into queue. The status is being set through a workflow rule as well - since the field update to the status didn't have the 'Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change' checked, that field update didn't trigger the other workflow rule... tricky - always be sure to check your settings.